# Can't find right LLVM in MacOS

Tags: eclipse-cdt, llvm, clang

I use Lion, have the latest xcode installed. So I believe that I have llvm, clang, and gcc4.2(because in xcode I can use them). Then I installed eclipse for c++ developers, after that I installed plugins llvm4eclipsecdt, and a set of plugins for parallel applications development (ptp). Ok. I built my code in eclipse. When I try to run it, it returns error `Launch failed. Binary not found`, although I specified `Match-O 64 Parser` in options. Perhaps, I should have specified where to find llvm as well(?).
In the debug folder there are files *.bc. I suppose it means llvm binary codes. I try `llv main.bc` but llv is not found! However, clang is installed and there are some strange files in the same folder like llvm-gcc-4.2 (another front end for llvm), llvm-g++ and so on. So where can I find llvm which I can use in console and specify this path in LLVM's plugin options in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the rest of the eclipse specifics but you probably wanted 'llc' not 'llv'. You'll find the binaries under /Developer. You generally don't want to run llc by hand though.